# ООП в статической библиотеке

Tags: c++, ооп, lib

Я не так давно узнал про статические/динамические библиотеки и у меня появился вопрос: Как сделать класс в статической библиотеке?? Я написал следующее для библиотеки:

```
extern "C"
{
    struct Sum
    {
        int sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    };
}
```

И это для использования:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    struct Sum
    {
        int sum(int, int);
    };
}

int main()
{
    Sum sum;
    std::cout << sum.sum(1, 1) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Но это не работает, ошибка линкера: LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: int __cdecl Sum::sum(int,int)" (?sum@Sum@@QEAAHHH@Z)

Как можно сделать нормальное ооп в статической библиотеке?

Comment: Это же ООП, С++ — какое уж тут `extern "C"`...

Comment: Зачем `extern "C"`?

Comment: ООП это стиль, а  не инструмент, чтобы его делать.  Оформляйте вопрос грамотно и  понятно. Лично я  не понял что вам нужно _ разница статической и динамической библиотеки или  способ подключения библиотек или как написать класс?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по ошибке LNK, вы используете Visual C++.

Вот ваш пример, переделанный в создание и использование статической библиотеки.

**sum.h**  Заголовочный файл для библиотеки

```
#pragma once
struct Sum {
    int sum(int a, int b);
    };
```

**sum.cpp**  Файл реализации

```
#include "Sum.h"
int Sum::sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

**main.cpp** Файл, использующий библиотеку

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sum.h"
int main() {
    Sum sum;
    std::cout << sum.sum(1, 1) << std::endl;
    }
```

Компиляция библиотечного файла в объектный:

```
cl -c sum.cpp
```

Сборка его в библиотеку `sumlib`:

```
lib /out:sumlib.lib Sum.obj
```

Компиляция главного файла с использованием библиотеки:

```
cl -EHsc main.cpp sumlib.lib
```

Все - библиотека создана и использована.